# WINAPI: Change color of (Radio) Button using Custom Draw?

Tags: winapi, comctl32

I simply need to change the text color of a radio control sometimes, so in the dialog procedure I setup:

```
case WM_NOTIFY:
{
  if (reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(lparam)->hdr.idFrom==IDC_RADIOMYCONTROLID) {
   if (reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(lparam)->hdr.code==NM_CUSTOMDRAW) {
      switch (reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(lparam)->dwDrawStage) {
        case CDDS_PREPAINT:
          // let it know we want to modify things.
          SetWindowLongPtr(hwnddlg, DWLP_MSGRESULT, CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW);
          return TRUE;

        case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
          // this is where we set up the colors
          SetTextColor(reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(lparam)->hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
          SetBkMode(reinterpret_cast<LPNMCUSTOMDRAW>(lparam)->hdc,TRANSPARENT);
          SetWindowLongPtr(hwnddlg, DWLP_MSGRESULT, CDRF_NEWFONT);
          return TRUE;
      }
    }
    break;
  }

  //...

  break;
}
```

The problem is that the CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT is not received.   In fact there are no more NM_CUSTOMDRAW messages after the CDDS_PREPAINT.

At first I was returning CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW directly until I remembered you have to put it in `DWLP_MSGRESULT`, but dang it, it still not working.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Not related to your problem, but your first two `reinterpret_cast`'s should be to `LPNMHDR` until you verify the message is actually `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`, only then can you safely cast to `LPNMCUSTOMDRAW`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons don't have "items" and so don't send the item (or sub-item) notifications. The only notifications they send are `CDDS_PREERASE`, `CDDS_PREPAINT`, `CDDS_POSTPAINT` and `CDDS_POSTERASE`.

However even if you change your code to set the text color when `CDDS_PREPAINT` is received, I don't think this is going to work for you. Unless themes are disabled, the button control takes its colors from the current system theme (visual style) and as far as I know ignores changes you make in response to `NM_CUSTOMDRAW`.

One solution would be to completely custom draw the control when handling `CDDS_PREPAINT`, but that's a lot more work.